# Exponential Waiting times with two queues

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

I am trying to understand the applications of exponential waiting times when there are two queues.

Let there be two counters in a mall, the first counter $X$ (where the order is placed), and the second counter $Y$ (where the item is collected).  When a customer arrives, they first go to counter $X$ to order, and then go to counter $Y$ to collect the item.

Also, serving times at each counter are independent and Exponential, with parameter $λ1$ at counter $X$, and parameter $λ2$ at counter $Y$.

If someone is already being served at a counter, the next customer waits in a queue.

For simplicity, I start with the following.  I assume that when I arrive, there is one customer at counter $X$, and no customer at counter $Y$ $($i. e., counter $Y$ is free when I arrive$)$.  How can I calculate the expected time I have to wait before collecting my order?

I have worked out the following:

$E($time I have to wait to collect my order$)$

= $E($time taken to serve the previous customer who's at counter $X$ when I arrive$)$ $+$ $E[$max $($$Tx$, $Ty$$)$$]$ $+$ $E($time taken to serve me at counter $Y$$)$

= $E(Tx)$ $+$ $(1/$$λ1$$)$ $+$ $(1/$$λ2$$)$ $-$ $(1/$$($$λ1$ + $λ2$$)$$)$ $+$ $E(Ty)$

The $2$nd, $3$rd and $4$th terms in the above sum are what I get for $E[$max $($$Tx$, $Ty$$)$$]$.  I am using the $E[$max $($$Tx$, $Ty$$)$$]$ because, when the previous customer is finished being served at counter $X$, the previous customer goes to counter $Y$, and I will start being served at counter $X$.

So here, there are 2 possibilities: $Tx$ > $Ty$, OR $Ty$ > $Tx$

$Tx$ ~ Exponential $($$λ1$$)$ and $Ty$ ~ Exponential $($$λ2$$)$.

Am I on the right track here?  Or have I missed something or not understanding it correctly?

Any insights are most appreciated.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular question, there are some shortcuts using the memoryless property of exponential distributions.

- You have to wait an expected time $\frac{1}{\lambda_1}$ for the other person to finish being served at the first counter
- Then you have to wait an expected time $\frac{1}{\lambda_1}$ to be served yourself at the first counter
- Then you may or may not need to wait for the other person to finish being served at the second counter; you have to wait with probability $\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}$ for an expected time  $\frac{1}{\lambda_2}$, so combined an expected  $\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)}$
- Finally you have to wait an expected time $\frac{1}{\lambda_2}$ to be served yourself at the second counter

Add these up: $\frac{2}{\lambda_1}+\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)} + \frac{1}{\lambda_2}$

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice!  I am trying to understand the third bullet point.  So here, after the previous customer is finished being served at the $1$st counter, I go to the $1$st counter and the previous customer goes to the $2$nd counter.  Now, we can have either T1 > T2, or T2 > T1.  If it takes longer for the previous customer in the $2$nd counter, then T2 > T1.  Therefore, I was thinking that we need to take $E($maximum of T1, T2$)$.  I understand the above logic in your explanation. If could also explain why E(max) doesn't work, I would be very grateful.  Thank you so much!

Comment: For the $2$nd bullet point, I was also wondering whether we need to take the combined expected using the following:  probability of not waiting at the $2$nd counter, which is $P(T1 > T2)$ = λ2 / (λ1 + λ2) for an expected time of 1 / λ1.  So the combined expected λ2 / [λ1(λ1 + λ2)].   This question arises because this is how we have worked out in the $3$rd bullet point, by considering the probability of the event happening.  Thank you once again for helping me understand this.  Have a great day!

Comment: If you are saying $T_x$ is you being served at the first counter and  $T_y$ is the other person being served at the second counter, then your expected queuing time at the second counter (my third bullet point) is $\mathbb E[\max(T_y-T_x,0)] $ $= \mathbb E[T_y-T_x \mid T_y>T_x]\,\mathbb P(T_y>T_x)+\mathbb E[0 \mid T_y\le T_x]\,\mathbb P(T_y\le T_x) $ $= \mathbb E[T_y]\,\mathbb P(T_y>T_x)+0$ by memorylessness and so $= \frac1{\lambda_2}\,\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+ \lambda_2}$

Comment: Clearly $\max(T_y, T_x)= T_x+\max(T_y-T_x,0)$ and so $\mathbb E[\max(T_y,T_x)] = \mathbb E[T_x]+\mathbb E[\max(T_y-T_x,0)]$, i.e. my second bullet point plus my third bullet point so $= \frac1{\lambda_1}+ \frac1{\lambda_2}\,\frac{\lambda_1}{(\lambda_1+ \lambda_2)}$

Comment: Thank you for explaining this!  I am working out the steps in your comments above in order to better understand!  So we need to consider the probability of waiting only in the 3rd bullet point, and not in the 2nd bullet point.  Is that correct?  Thank you once again.

Comment: @probstudent.  The second bullet point is you being served at the first counter (this will take time).  The third bullet is you subsequently queuing for the second counter (this may or may not take time).

Comment: I got it!!!  Thank you so much!  I just worked it out step by step and read through your comments above when I was stuck... Thanks once again! :)